# How to call again LiveData Coroutine Block

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel

I'm using LiveData's version "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0-alpha05". Once my LiveData block executes successfully I want to explicitly trigger it to execute again, e.g.

1. I navigate to a fragment
2. User's data loads
3. I click delete btn while being in the same fragment
4. User's data should refresh

I have a fragment where I observe my LiveData, a ViewModel with LiveData and Repository:

ViewModel:

> ```
>   fun getUserLiveData() = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
>
>    val userData = usersRepo.getUser(userId)
>
>    emit(userData) 
> }
> ```

Fragment:

> ```
> viewModel.getUserLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner,
>             androidx.lifecycle.Observer {..
> ```

Then I'm trying to achieve desired behaviour like this:

> ```
> viewModel.deleteUser()
>
> viewModel.getUserLiveData()
> ```

According to the documentation below LiveData block won't execute if it has completed successfully and if I put a **while(true)** inside the LiveData block, then my data refreshes, however I don't want this to do since I need to update my view reactively.

> If the [block] completes successfully *or* is cancelled due to reasons other than [LiveData]
>    becoming inactive, it *will not* be re-executed even after [LiveData] goes through active
>    inactive cycle.

Perhaps I'm missing something how I can reuse the same LiveDataScope to achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you find solution

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: what your repo calls ? is it Room Database or a server call ?

Comment: @MojtabaHaddadi it fetches data from a server.

Comment: Any luck @JanasC12, i'm in the same position now. All these fancy apis for nothing lol

Comment: Did you find a solution?   I am wondering the same

Answer (score 2):

To do this with liveData { .. } block you need to define some source of commands and then subscribe to them in a block. Example:

```
MyViewModel() : ViewModel() {
   val commandsChannel = Channel<Command>()

   val liveData = livedata {
      commandsChannel.consumeEach { command -> 
            // you could have different kind of commands 
             //or emit just Unit to notify, that refresh is needed
           val newData = getSomeNewData()
           emit(newData)
       }
   }

  fun deleteUser() {
   .... // delete user
   commandsChannel.send(RefreshUsersListCommand)
  }
}
```

Question you should ask yourself: Maybe it would be easier to use ordinary MutableLiveData instead, and mutate its value by yourself?

livedata { ... } builder works well, when you can collect some stream of data (like a Flow / Flowable from Room DB) and not so well for plain, non stream sources, which you need to ask for data by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for this. We can use `switchMap` to call the `LiveDataScope` manually.

First, let see the official example for `switchMap`:

```kotlin
/**
 * Here is an example class that holds a typed-in name of a user
 * `String` (such as from an `EditText`) in a [MutableLiveData] and
 * returns a `LiveData` containing a List of `User` objects for users that have
 * that name. It populates that `LiveData` by requerying a repository-pattern object
 * each time the typed name changes.
 * <p>
 * This `ViewModel` would permit the observing UI to update "live" as the user ID text
 * changes.
**/
class UserViewModel: AndroidViewModel {
    val nameQueryLiveData : MutableLiveData<String> = ...

    fun usersWithNameLiveData(): LiveData<List<String>> = nameQueryLiveData.switchMap {
        name -> myDataSource.usersWithNameLiveData(name)
    }

    fun setNameQuery(val name: String) {
        this.nameQueryLiveData.value = name;
    }
}
```

The example was very clear. We just need to change `nameQueryLiveData` to your own type and then combine it with `LiveDataScope`. Such as:

```kotlin
class UserViewModel: AndroidViewModel {
    val _action : MutableLiveData<NetworkAction> = ...

    fun usersWithNameLiveData(): LiveData<List<String>> = _action.switchMap {
        action -> liveData(Dispatchers.IO){
            when (action) {
                Init -> {
                    // first network request or fragment reusing
                    // check cache or something you saved.
                    val cache = getCache()
                    if (cache == null) {
                        // real fecth data from network
                        cache = repo.loadData()
                    }
                    saveCache(cache)
                    emit(cache)
                }
                Reload -> {
                    val ret = repo.loadData()
                    saveCache(ret)
                    emit(ret)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // call this in activity, fragment or any view
    fun fetchData(ac: NetworkAction) {
        this._action.value = ac;
    }

    sealed class NetworkAction{
        object Init:NetworkAction()
        object Reload:NetworkAction()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First add `implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0"` to your gradle file. Make your `ViewModel` as follows:

```
MyViewModel() : ViewModel() {
   val userList = MutableLiveData<MutableList<User>>()

   fun getUserList() {
       viewModelScope.launch {
           userList.postValue(usersRepo.getUser(userId))
       }
   }
}
```

Then onserve the userList:

```
viewModel.sessionChartData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { users ->
    // Do whatever you want with "users" data
})
```

Make an `extension` to delete single user from userList and get notified:

```
fun <T> MutableLiveData<MutableList<T>>.removeItemAt(index: Int) {
    if (!this.value.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        val oldValue = this.value
        oldValue?.removeAt(index)
        this.value = oldValue
    } else {
        this.value = mutableListOf()
    }
}
```

Call that extension function to delete any user and you will be notified in your `Observer` block after one user get deleted.

```
viewModel.userList.removeItemAt(5) // Index 5
```

When you want to get userList from data source just call `viewModel.getUserList()` You will get data to the observer block.

Answer (score 0):

```
private val usersLiveData = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val retrievedUsers = MyApplication.moodle.getEnrolledUsersCoroutine(course)
    repo.users = retrievedUsers
    roles.postValue(repo.findRolesByAll())
    emit(retrievedUsers)
}

init {
    usersMediator.addSource(usersLiveData){ usersMediator.value = it }
}

fun refreshUsers() {
    usersMediator.removeSource(usersLiveData)
    usersMediator.addSource(usersLiveData) { usersMediator.value = it }
```

The commands in liveData block {} doesn't get executed again.
Okay yes, the observer in the viewmodel holding activity get's triggered, but with old data.
No further network call.

Sad. Very sad. "Solution" seemed promisingly and less boilerplaty compared to the other suggestions with Channel and SwitchMap mechanisms.

Comment: Your code example is unclear for me! but additional description is good. If you explain more about your code, I'll like to upvote you. What is relation between roles? what does roles.postValue(repo.findRolesByAll())?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [MediatorLiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData.html) for this.

The following is a gist of how you may be able to achieve this.

```
class YourViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val mediatorLiveData = MediatorLiveData<String>()

    private val liveData = liveData<String> {  }

    init {
        mediatorLiveData.addSource(liveData){mediatorLiveData.value = it}
    }

    fun refresh() {
        mediatorLiveData.removeSource(liveData)
        mediatorLiveData.addSource(liveData) {mediatorLiveData.value = it}
    }
}
```

Expose `mediatorLiveData` to your `View` and `observe()` the same, call `refresh()` when your user is deleted and the rest should work as is.